# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Which architecture should I use?

Tags: c++, macos

I'm trying to do some really simple stuff in C++, but I can't find any information on how to tackle this. Even the book I have just says "Just compile and run the program".

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    cout << "Never fear, C++ is here!"; 
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler says:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in ccVfJHGs.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccVfJHGs.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccVfJHGs.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_0 in ccVfJHGs.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried compiling with flags like `-arch i386` and `-m32` but it always says it's the wrong architecture. Which one should I use?

I'm doing this on a Mac but not using XCode, just gcc.

Comment: Which gcc do you use? Macports? XCode? Looks like your path is messed up.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The error isn't that it's the wrong architecture, it's that `std::cout` (and other symbols) isn't defined.

You should compile and link with `g++` not `gcc`, to automatically link with correct C++ libraries.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Why isn't gcc working for me? Every example I see is using gcc, is it a os x thing?

Comment: @oskob No, it's simply because gcc is the C compiler (though it handles C++ syntax), and g++ is the C++ compiler.

Comment: Isn't gcc a front-end which will delegate to g++ when it encounters .cc / .cpp files?

Comment: `g++` passes `-lstdc++` to the linker, `gcc` doesn't and that's the only difference.

Comment: Thank you!
You just saved me a bunch of time!

Answer (score 5):

The error is caused because you're compiling with `gcc`, which only default-links `libc`.
You need to compile with `g++` so that `libstdc++` is auto-linked in too.

Answer (score 2):

Use g++ instead of gcc to link with exact c++ libraries

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer. Please obtain the rep to post it as such.