# Can non-static member function access static member function or data?

Tags: c++, class, static

I searched the Internet and found that some people said that non-static member function can access static member function or data. Then I wrote a program to verify it.

```
#include <iostream>
class test
{
public:
    static int a;
    void printa()
    {
        std::cout<<a;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    test m;
    m.printa();

    return 0;
}
```

The code generate linker errors!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test::a", referenced from:
      test::printa() in main.o
```

Comment: Here is similar problem and its solution is  
[Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034568/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-which-architecture-should-i-use

Answer (score 8):

Declaring a variable as `static` inside a class is, well, *only* a declaration.

You need to *define* the variable as well, which means adding this line in a single compilation unit :

`int test::a = 0;`

To be more precise : a compilation unit is basically a .cpp file. You should *not* put that line directly in a header file, otherwise you will get the opposite error : "multiple definition of...".

This will also, as you have guessed, initialize your variable to `0` once your program starts.

If you put this line under your class declaration, it will fix your problem (in this specific situation : remember not to write this in a header file).

Comment: worth adding "don't put it in a header file", since not everybody knows what "compilation unit" means.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you've only declared `test::a`, not defined it:

```
#include <iostream>
class test
{
    ...
};

int test::a = 1; //Needs a definition!
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only declared the `static` data member. You have not defined it.

YOu need to do something like `int test:: a;` to define it.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300652/static-data-member-initialization) too

Non-static members are allowed to access static data members. The reverse is not allowed because static members do not belong to any object

Answer (score 0):

You must define the static data member instance.  Add a line...

```
int test::a;
```

...above `main()`, or under `main()`... basically anywhere directly in the same namespace scope as `class test` and after `class test`'s definition.

Comment: it doesn't matter where it will be defined.

Comment: @Elazar: that's a cyclic argument, because if you try to put it somewhere illegal it won't be defined ;-P. My suggestion of above `main` was to ensure that a definition wasn't *attempted* within `main()` (which would constitute another declaration), nor before or inside `class test`....

Comment: @elazar that's not completely true. The declaration of the class that it is member of needs to be visible.

Comment: @TonyD then edit your answer to reflect that, otherwise it is misleading.

Comment: @Elazar: I think "misleading" is a bit strong... but no harm so have clarified. Cheers.  Maybe you should suggest Nbr44 make similar changes for "If you put this line under your class declaration, it will fix your problem."...?

Comment: @tonyD did i say declaration? Yes yes, definition :)