# Cannot run Helloworld.cpp in C++ in VS Code (MacOS) (Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, linker, undefined-symbol

I run:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello world"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It's just a simple C++ program, I don't know what's wrong with my environment seeting.
Could you please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: did you save your source file before compiling?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034568/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-which-architecture-should-i-use

Comment: @XraySensei Well, in that case the compiler (or rather, linker) did not complain about main.

Comment: @AlanBirtles That may well be the case. Gloria, [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JA4jUFiy_io) is a video showing you how to adjust the settings so that saving is done automatically before each run. It's also my standard setting in the full-fledged Visual Studio: I think I never wanted to run a version of my program that didn't contain my latest edits.

Comment: @Gloria1009 Great :-).